# Hitting Escape versus Enter triggering LVN_ENDLABELEDIT in CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, listbox, clistctrl

how can I differentiate between the two, when the edit field is empty in both cases?
when the user hits escape, I assume user doesn't want the new value at all, when
enter is hit, I assume the user wants an empty string for the edited item...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyPropertyPage, CPropertyPage)
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyPropertyPage)
    ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ENDLABELEDIT, IDC_LIST_CONTROL, OnEndLabelEdit)
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyPropertyPage::OnEndLabelEdit(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    LV_DISPINFO* pDispInfo = (LV_DISPINFO*)pNMHDR;
    if (pDispInfo->item.pszText == NULL)
    {
             //Used clicked escape
     }
     else
     {
            //Data was accepted by user, empty string perhaps?
     }
}
```

Comment: It's not correct answer. If user doesn't change the item text and press "Enter", `pDispInfo->item.pszText` will be *NULL* as well!  So you can not detect whether it was canceling by Escape or  leaving text unchanged by Enter key.